Show that a uniform space is complete iff every Cauchy ultrafilter converges
A uniform space $(X,\Phi)$ Wikipedia
is said to be complete if every Cauchy filter (a filter such that for every $U \in \Phi$  , there exists $A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $A \times A \subset U$) converges.
I have shown that this is equivalent to requiring that every Cauchy net ( a net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ satisfying the following condition: for every $U \in \Phi$ (a member of the uniformity), there exists an $i_0 \in I$ such that $(x_i,x_j) \in U$ for all $i,j \ge i_0$) converges.
From this, it is straightforward to see that if $(X,\Phi)$ is complete, then every Cauchy ultrafilter converges. However, I am struggling with the reverse direction: showing that if every Cauchy ultrafilter converges, then $(X,\Phi)$ is complete.
My attempt: I considered an arbitrary Cauchy filter $\mathcal{F}$and extended it to an ultrafilter $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{U}$. Since $\mathcal{U}$ is a Cauchy ultrafilter, it converges by assumption. However, this only guarantees the convergence of the net induced by $\mathcal{U}$, and it is unclear to me how to deduce the convergence of the original filter $\mathcal{F}$.
However, this sadly led to no further progress and I am stuck and would appreciate some help.

Connected.

@JeanMarie I do not see how this Link helps. Since looking at the associated nets I still only get that the ultra fine Cauchy net converges and not the net associated to my filter

First, a useful lemma
It turns out that to prove that a Cauchy filter converges, it is sufficient to prove that it has a cluster point, which is a little less demanding (if $\mathcal F$ is a filter on a topological space $X$, a cluster point of $\mathcal F$ in $X$ is a point of $X$ that is in the closure in $X$ of every element of $\mathcal F$).

Lemma. — A Cauchy filter $\mathcal F$ on a uniform space $X$ converges in $X$ if and only if it has a cluster point in $X$.

Proof. — If $\mathcal F$ converges in $X$, then any limit of $\mathcal F$ in $X$ is of course a cluster point of $\mathcal F$ in $X$. Conversely, suppose that $\mathcal F$ has a cluster point $x$ in $X$. I will show that $\mathcal F$ converges to $x$. Since the sets of the form $U(x)$ as $U$ ranges over the uniformity of $X$ form a basis of the filter of neighbourhoods of $x$ in $X$, it suffices to show that if $U$ is an entourage of $X$, then $U(x)\in\mathcal F$.
So let $U$ be an entourage of $X$. Let $V$ be an entourage of $X$ such that $V\circ V\subset U$. Since $\mathcal F$ is a Cauchy filter, there is a set $A\in\mathcal F$ that such that $A\times A\subset V$. To show that $U(x)\in\mathcal F$, it is sufficient to show that $A\subseteq U(x)$, which I will do next.
Let $z\in A$. Since $x$ is a cluster point of $\mathcal F$, it is in the closure of $A$ in $X$, and since $V(x)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, the intersection $A\cap V(x)$ is nonempty; let $y\in A\cap V(x)$. The relations $y\in V(x)$ and $(y,z)\in A\times A$ then imply $(x,y)\in V$ and $(y,z)\in V$ ($A\times A\subset V$), which shows that $(x,z)\in V\circ V\subset U$ and then that $z\in U(x)$, which concludes.
Back to your question
You have a Cauchy filter $\mathcal F$ on $X$ and an ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $X$, finer than $\mathcal F$ and which converges in $X$. Any limit of $\mathcal U$ in $X$ is of course a cluster point of $\mathcal U$ in $X$, and since $\mathcal U$ is finer than $\mathcal F$, any limit of $\mathcal U$ in $X$ is also a cluster point of $\mathcal F$ in $X$. The useful lemma from above then shows that $\mathcal F$ converges in $X$.

Thank you for your solution. It is exceptionally well-written and remarkably clear, making it easy to follow and understand.
